# Hot to get PHP variables in JSON format and refresh by AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, xml

I have a device which export data in XML format.
And I would like to display this data on my webpage + refresh every second by ajax.

So my PHP file is:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://admin:pass@192.168.0.109/st0.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo json_encode($xml);
exit();
```

this will display:

{"out0":"1","out1":"1","out2":"1","out3":"1","out4":"1","out5":"1","out6":"1","di0":"up","di1":"up","di2":"up","di3":"up","ia0":"473","ia1":"166","ia2":"359","ia3":"187","ia4":"4326","ia5":"1832","ia6":"36","ia7":"198","ia8":"6","ia9":"234","ia10":"-600","ia11":"246","ia12":"-600","ia13":"0","ia14":"0","ia15":"65952","ia16":"0","ia17":"854000","ia18":"1000","ia19":"192","freq":"5008","duty":"500","pwm":"0","sec0":"27","sec1":"17","sec2":"20","sec3":"1","sec4":"1481894628"}

So now I know how to display whole data and refresh, but I do not now how to put every data in separete div, ex. to display only interesting part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#load_results").load("get_xml.php");
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "load_results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not put them into a table?

Comment: Why are you converting the XML into JSON? Just pass the XML, load it into jQuery and use the jQuery Api to get data from it.

Comment: @Thw: Actually you are right, I do not need JSON. Just didn't know how to pass the XML to query and then display specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 situations:

1. Either you know the format of the JSON and you can build a DOM
   structure using jQuery (for example) in the exact format you want
   with the exact data you have.

For that you will have to access the object properties of the JSON object so for instance:

```
$("#load_results").load("get_xml.php");
```

becomes:

```
$.get( "get_xml.php", function( data ) { // retrieves the JSON from that file using AJAX
    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data); // we convert the JSON string into a Javascript object

    var formattedString = 'Our OUT0 is ' + parsedJSON.out0 + '<br>'; // we access the data in the Javascript object as for all Javascript objects, see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
    formattedString = formattedString + 'Our ia12 is ' + parsedJSON.ia12; // and so on

    $('#load_results').html(formattedString);
});
```

2. Either you don't know the format or
   you don't care at all. In this case the situation is simpler, you
   can use a JSON prettifying tool for JavaScript such as the one
   implemented here: http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/ (by someone else than me, cheers to him).

For the option 2 this would be the library:

```
// Library
window.jsonPrettifier = {
   replacer: function(match, pIndent, pKey, pVal, pEnd) {
      var key = '<span class=json-key>';
      var val = '<span class=json-value>';
      var str = '<span class=json-string>';
      var r = pIndent || '';
      if (pKey)
         r = r + key + pKey.replace(/[": ]/g, '') + '</span>: ';
      if (pVal)
         r = r + (pVal[0] == '"' ? str : val) + pVal + '</span>';
      return r + (pEnd || '');
      },
   prettyPrint: function(obj) {
      var jsonLine = /^( *)("[\w]+": )?("[^"]*"|[\w.+-]*)?([,[{])?$/mg;
      return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3)
         .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\\"/g, '&quot;')
         .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
         .replace(jsonLine, library.json.replacer);
      }
   };
```

After you added this library somewhere inside your code, you can replace

```
$("#load_results").load("get_xml.php");
```

with

```
$.get( "get_xml.php", function( data ) { // retrieves the JSON from that file using AJAX
  var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#load_results').html(window.jsonPrettifier.prettyPrint(parsedJSON));
});
```

and you will obtain a pretty printed JSON.

Comment: thanx for comments, but in my case I need to display only some parts of the data. Ex. out1 and out2 and pwm, so I would like to have specific variable to display. In PHP I can call an element in array, but I do not know how to do it in JS/jquery

Comment: So the problem is that you want to access the JSON object as in Option 1. I've expanded the Option 1 explanation a bit, hope it makes sense.

Comment: why can't you just do the data fiddling/displaying in the php file and ajax the results?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, it's not like the person who is asking stated that he wanted to use php as his template engine/output generator.

Comment: but he maybe also might not know it